# How do I set up a rails app where many users are uploading images at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, upload

I like to use heroku and paperclip for image uploads. Usually my users don't need to upload many images.

I'm now embarking on a website where many users will be trying to upload images at the same time. Unfortunately on heroku, it seems I need a separate dyno for every image upload, otherwise the site becomes unresponsive. Or am I missing something?

What is an optimal way to set up a rails application (not necessarily on Heroku) where the site can easily deal with (in a scalable way, ideally) multiple uploads at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcoming with Heroku - it doesn't handle file uploads very efficiently.  See [this article](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/6-ways-to-get-more-bang-for-your-heroku-buck-while-making-your-rails-site-super-snappy/) that discusses this point, among others.  The author suggests using the [carrierwave_direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) gem or the [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) service.  <s>Neither concept will work well for Paperclip as it doesn't provide cloud storage support.</s>  You might want to move to CarrierWave for easier implementation of these concepts.

Comment: I'll look into these. Paperclip does allow S3 storage, it's just that the data sending and then the processing lock up the app.

Comment: @pixelearth: I'm not sure why I thought this, perhaps this was added more recently?  In any event, I typically find CarrierWave more flexible for significant deviations from the standard workflow, although Paperclip might still work for you - updated to reflect this.